# How to copy last row from google sheet and copy to last row of other google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried every example and have been working on this for days, appreciate any help. I just want to copy the last row from one sheet and copy it to the last row of another sheet. This last example copies all the rows, not just the last row.

I have tried every sample and example I could find without success.

```
function lastrow2() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY ID');
var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY ID')
var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet2');
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 
sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 
sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
targetrange.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

I expected just to get the last row from the source sheet and copy it into the last row of the target sheet, instead it copies all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to copy a values of last row of Sheet1 to the last row of Sheet2.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

#### Note:

If you want to overwrite to the last row of Sheet2, please modify from `targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn())` to `targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn())`.

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit:

From your comment, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var targetsheet = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
```

#### To:

```
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The first From: To: works but appends a new line to the source. When I use the code to overwrite I get. The starting row of the range is too small here: var targetsheet = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sourcesheet.getLastColumn());

Comment: @Burt Lewis Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

## Copy lastrow of one spreadsheet to the last row of another spreadsheet

#### Neither spreadsheet is the script container in my tests

*But one of them could have been.*

```
function copyLastToLast() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1u1d-eJVnR_UdAY_1ZnuF0kF3LLdnq30XIKW3wnQSFCY');
  var ssh=sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var srg=ssh.getRange(ssh.getLastRow(),1,1,ssh.getLastColumn());
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('13hXYw9wrZtIi2OayGGurD2qOXZLaNcEZoculd179B_0');
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  if(tsh.getLastRow()) {
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow(),1,1,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);
  }else{
    tsh.getRange(1,1,1,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I get "The starting row of the range is too small." at this line: tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow(),1,1,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);

Comment: If there is no data on the target sheet then `tsh.getLastRow()=0`. I gave you what you asked for but I suspect that you wanted the lastRow + 1.

Comment: Yes, I want to either overwrite line 1 or replace it. Hi, sorry but I'm getting various new errors, maybe I'm not understanding how to write your new  change? This is what I have now but have tried 0, and =0 with errors. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just copy the new answer. I modified it.  If the targetsheet doesn't have any rows then it puts it in line 1.